# How to unpivot one table into another table so that each row exists or is duplicated

Tags: sql

I have a table `Table_1` which has a list of SKU:

```
| SKU |
| R001 | 
| R002 |
| R003 |
```

I then have a second table `Table_2` which contains a list of sites:

```
| Site |
| Store1 | 
| Store2 |
| Store3 |
```

I'd like to combine these tables so that each `SKU` exists at each `Site`.

So far I have the following:

```
SELECT
    [Table_1].[SKU],
    [Table_2].[Site]
FROM 
    [Table_1]
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    [Table_2] ON [Table_1].[SKU] = [Table_2].[Site]
```

This keeps on producing an error message based on conversion attempting to convert a `SKU` from type `Varchar` to `Int`.

Any advice or guidance on how to do this would be great please.

Thanks

Comment: This does not make sense: `ON [Table_1].[SKU] = [Table_2].[Site]` . You need `cross join`, no `on` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will bring each possible pair using both tables.

```
   select * from table1 cross join table2
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect and much simpler than i was attempting!